# How to execute a JSP and print the result in the same HTML but not in the JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, jsp

I am developing a web application which has some tabs (Home, About, Search). So basically what it does is in the Search tab, there is a text box. User provides some input in the text box then HTML page retrieves information regarding the entered input from Database (MySQL) and displays on a similar looking jsp page. Since, I am using tabs there is only one HTML web page. I have a JSP page which perform the Database Connectivity and retrieves data. My html elements in the JSP page are exactly like my HTML page.

Is there any way to efficiently code this application? The below code works fine though.

Because I feel that its redundant to include same HTML in both HTML and JSP page, all because we want the data in the same page. Please help me out!!

Versions I am using

- Java 8.0.18
- Eclipse Oxygen
- MySQL Workbench 6.3
- Apache Tomcat 7.0

My HTML code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="styleSheet" href=url>
        <script src=url></script>
        <title>Search App</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <!-- Header of webpage -->
    <div class="header">
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/SearchApp/html/index.html"><img src=url height=80 width=200/></a> 
    </div>

    <!-- Tab links -->
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Home')" class="active">Home</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'About')">About</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Search')">Search</button>
        </div>
    <br><br>

    <!-- Left Tab content -->
    <div class="column left">

        <div id="Home" class="tabcontent" style=display:block>
            <h3>Home</h3> <br>
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp blah blah blah
        </div>

        <div id="About" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>About</h3> <br>
            blah blah blah
        </div>

        <div id="Search" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Search</h3><br>
            <form method="GET" action="http://localhost:8080/SearchApp/jsp/action.jsp">
                Search for: <input type="text" name="searchElement"><br><br>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JSP Page is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="styleSheet" href=url>
        <script src=url></script>

        <title>Search App</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Header of webpage -->
    <div class="header">
        <a href="http://localhost:8080/SearchApp/html/index.html"><img src=url height=80 width=200/></a> 
    </div>

    <!-- Tab links -->
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'About')">About</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Search')" class="active">Search</button>
        </div>
    <br><br>

    <!-- Left Tab content -->
        <div class="column left">
            <div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
                <h3>Home</h3> <br>
                &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp blah blah blah
            </div>

            <div id="About" class="tabcontent">
                <h3>About</h3> <br>
                blah blah blah
            </div>

            <div id="Search" class="tabcontent" style=display:block>
                <h3>Search</h3><br>
                <form method="GET" action="http://localhost:8080/SearchApp/jsp/action.jsp">
                    Search for: <input type="text" name="searchElement"><br><br>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
                <br>
                 <%
                    String searchID=request.getParameter("searchElement"); 
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root",""); 
                    Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select valueSearch from SearchElement where keySearch='"+searchID+"'"); 
                    if(rs.isBeforeFirst())
                    {
                        out.println("Search Results for: "+searchID+"\n\n");
                %>
                        <table>
                <%
                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                %>          <tr><td> <%= rs.getString("valueSearch") %> </td></tr>
                <%
                        }
                %>
                <%  }
                    else
                    {
                        out.println("No Search Results for: "+searchID);
                    }
                %>
                        </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS Style sheet

```
body {
    font-family:arial;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: black;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
} 

/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left; 
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Left column */
.column.left {
    width: 70%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width:600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

My JavaScript code

```
function openLink(evt, tabName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: The entire point of a view-rendering technology such as JSP is to render HTML pages with custom data (such as from a database). You are correct in that this redundancy is a code smell. You only need JSPs

Comment: So, Is this acceptable way of coding? I mean is this how it is? Sorry, I am a fresher who recently started working. I am not sure if I can code in this way.

Comment: No it is not the right way to do it. You use the JSP to generate the HTML page

Comment: okay. I got it. Thank you so much!!